# MySQL: Join query across multiple databases located on different servers

Tags: php, mysql

In SQL Server there is a way to [join tables from multiple sql servers by using link tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171899/joining-tables-from-multiple-sql-server-databases-located-on-separate-severs).

I wonder whether is it possible to do the same? I am using PHP, does PHP provides this kind of facilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't necessarily easy, nor pretty, but this article gives some solutions to your problem:
http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/52390

**UPDATE**

Since the link is gone now, here is more text

Creating a linked server using OLE DB for SQL Server 
This example creates a linked server named MyDatabase that uses the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server.

```
USE master
GO
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
'MyDatabase',
N'SQL Server'
GO
```

Then you can reference as though they are on the same server, so if the databases are on the same mssql server then skip the above step and just do the following:

[Server name].[database name].[owner].table_name

Comment: your link is not working anymore, could you edit your answer and add at least some phrases I can use to search for these solutions?

Comment: @OriesokVlassky - Added text, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

Try the federated storage engine to link to tables on other servers.

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-federated-storage.html