# How we can access a table in mysql which is exist in another database?

Tags: mysql

There are two databases: `First` and `Second`, 
First includes table A and Second Includes table B
Now
I want to access table B while using database First.
What query should I run in MySql?

Comment: further details what table is, what field is what type of fields are those andy sample input what's expected etc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Join Query Across Multiple Databases Located on Different Servers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622857/mysql-join-query-across-multiple-databases-located-on-different-servers)

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT *
 FROM `database1`.`mycol1`
  WHERE option_name="blah"
UNION
SELECT *
 FROM `database2`.`my_col2`
  WHERE option_name="blah"
```

You can use this. .

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this syntax is used to select from `TABLE`s, not databases. Does anyone else have input on this?

Comment: @fond42518 You can test this code its working fine to work with two databases . .

Answer (score 0):

use this

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DBNAME.* TO username@host; IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`
than after fire queries what you want. like below query

```
SELECT a.* FROM databaseA.tabA a
LEFT JOIN databaseB.TabB b ON a.id=b.id 
WHERE b.id IS NOT NULL;`
```

depending on the fields matching between tabA and tabB.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [the following syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188366.aspx) to perform a SQL operation in any mySQL schema:

```
USE database_name
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a sample:

[Joining MySQL tables across multiple databases](http://nathan.rambeck.org/blog/2-joining-mysql-tables-across-multiple-databases)

```
SELECT a.* FROM database1.tableA a
LEFT JOIN database2.TableB b ON a.id=b.id 
WHERE b.id IS NOT NULL;
```

*You need to prefix the table reference with the name of the database it resides in.*

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the [`join`](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/) syntax, which creates a relationship between `First table` and `Second table`. Basically, you can access a table in another database by fully qualifying it, for example:

`select * from [databasename].[tablename];`

Answer (score 0):

try to do something like below :

```
select * from second.B
```